# C# ASP.NET send email if date in database is older than a month from today

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, events, logging

I have an ASP.NET MVC app (not .NET Core), using Entity Framework.
I have a class like this:

```
class Unicorn
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan MaximalAge { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like to be able to email or log when the unicorn gets too old.
What is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already tried or thought about some routes you could go down? What research have you done? Might be easier for someone to provide help knowing what you have tried and researched.

Comment: Need more information to understand the problem.  If we assume you want the email to go out independent of any operator action, you could use a scheduled task to query the back-end data source and send an email.  You *could* write a C# program to do it, but powershell or other scripting solution is probably better suited.

Comment: I know it would be easy if there was some loop and in that loop was a simple if statement, but in web apps, there isn't any.